# How to get rid of a node that shows as null after being replaced?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I had a 3 nodes cluster (Cassandra 3.9) ; one node went dead.
I built a new node from scratch and "replaced" the dead node using the information from this page https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html.
It looked like the replacement went ok.

I added two more nodes to strengthen the cluster.

A few days have passed and the dead node is still visible and marked as "down" on 3 of 5 nodes in `nodetool status`:

```
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.9   16 GiB     256          35.0%             76223d4c-9d9f-417f-be27-cebb791cddcc  rack1
UN  192.168.1.12  16.09 GiB  256          34.0%             719601e2-54a6-440e-a379-c9cf2dc20564  rack1
UN  192.168.1.14  14.16 GiB  256          32.6%             d8017a03-7e4e-47b7-89b9-cd9ec472d74f  rack1
UN  192.168.1.17  15.4 GiB   256          34.1%             fa238b21-1db1-47dc-bfb7-beedc6c9967a  rack1
DN  192.168.1.18  24.3 GiB   256          33.7%             null                                  rack1
UN  192.168.1.22  19.06 GiB  256          30.7%             09d24557-4e98-44c3-8c9d-53c4c31066e1  rack1
```

Its host ID is null, so I cannot use `nodetool removenode`. Moreover 
`nodetool assassinate 192.168.1.18` fails with :

```
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And in system.log:

```
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(16)-127.0.0.1] 2019-03-27 17:39:38,595 Gossiper.java:585 - Sleeping for 30000ms to ensure /192.168.1.18 does not change
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:547] 2019-03-27 17:39:38,669 AutoSavingCache.java:393 - Saved KeyCache (27316 items) in 163 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2019-03-27 17:40:03,620 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:75 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(16)-127.0.0.1] 2019-03-27 17:40:08,597 Gossiper.java:1029 - InetAddress /192.168.1.18 is now DOWN
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(16)-127.0.0.1] 2019-03-27 17:40:08,599 StorageService.java:2324 - Removing tokens [-1061369577393671924,...]
```

In `system.peers`, the dead node shows and has the same ID as the replacing node :

```
cqlsh> select peer, host_id from system.peers;

 peer         | host_id
--------------+--------------------------------------
 192.168.1.18 | 09d24557-4e98-44c3-8c9d-53c4c31066e1
 192.168.1.22 | 09d24557-4e98-44c3-8c9d-53c4c31066e1
  192.168.1.9 | 76223d4c-9d9f-417f-be27-cebb791cddcc
 192.168.1.14 | d8017a03-7e4e-47b7-89b9-cd9ec472d74f
 192.168.1.12 | 719601e2-54a6-440e-a379-c9cf2dc20564
```

Dead node and replacing node have different tokens in `system.peers`.

So my questions are :

- Could you explain what is wrong ?
- How can fix this and get rid of this dead node ?

Answer (score 0):

From system.peers you got the host id, so can you try nodetool removenode/assassinate with the host id.

```
 peer         | host_id
 --------------+--------------------------------------
  192.168.1.18 | 09d24557-4e98-44c3-8c9d-53c4c31066e1
```

Comment: As this host id is now used by live node as he replaced it with old one, it may assassinate the current live node.

Comment: Indeed I have two ip addresses with the same node ID. Will it kill both ?

Comment: SELECT peer, host_id, TTL(host_id)  FROM system.peers where peer='192.168.1.18'; -- This might help in getting to know if the TTL in seconds was set for that host.

Comment: TTL is null. I am currently reviewing Cassandra's source to understand the cause of the Java exception. I might also add a few more nodes and decommission / remove the 3 nodes that have 192.168.1.18 in their peers.